# Visual Studio C++ Express 2010 - does it work with unmanaged code?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010

Does Visual Studio C++ Express 2010 work with unmanaged code? Or is it only managed?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it does work with unmanaged code.